# Save excel file with current date and time through javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to open the excel file and then save the excel file and the name will be file name + current date and time. I am not getting this result for date I have used `Date()`

```
var wshell;
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
alert(excel);
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("book2.xlsx");
excel.Visible = true;

var objWorkbook = excel.Workbooks.Add();
var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1);

objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate;
objWorksheet.name = "test";
objWorksheet.Paste;
objWorksheet.columns.autofit;
window.clipboardData.setData("Text","");
var today = new Date();

document.write(today.toString());
excel_file.SaveAs("d:\\board.xls"+ (today.toString()));
alert("data saved");
```

Comment: What is the current output file name? What is the desired filename?

Comment: I suppose you're aware this is far from cross-browser compatible ?

Comment: desired file name could be anything there is no restriction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`today` contains an illegal character (`:`) to use in a file name. You need to clean your date, for example something like this:

```
var today = new Date().toString().replace(/[^\w]/g, '');
```

And when saving, the timestamp should be a part of the file name instead of the extension:

```
excel_file.SaveAs("D:\\board" + today + ".xls");
```

Instead of `.toString().replace()` you can format the timestamp to look like you want with methods of [`Date object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

---

**EDIT**

Here's the code with which you can modify your dates. I've simplified `getDate()` for you, hence you can modify it to return a date in what ever form you want.

```
var today = new Date(),
    time = today.toTimeString().split(':').join('').substr(0, 4),
    timestamp = getDate('dd_mm_yyyy', today) + '_' + time;

function getDate (mode, userdate) {
    var dte = userdate || new Date(),
        d = dte.getDate().toString(),
        m = (dte.getMonth() + 1).toString(),
        yyyy = dte.getFullYear().toString(),
        dd = (d.length < 2) ? '0' + d : d,
        mm = (m.length < 2) ? '0' + m : m,
        yy = yyyy.substring(2, 4);
    switch (mode) {
        case 'dd_mm_yyyy': return dd + '_' + mm + '_' + yyyy;
        case 'yyyymmdd': return yyyy + mm + dd;
        default: return dte;
    }
}
```

`timestamp` contains a date in wanted form after run the code above.

Comment: AFTER SAVING THE FILE I want the file format like this "InvoicenDetails20_NOV_2013_12_2355" means FILE NAME THEN DD-MM-YY THEN TIME.

Comment: You can extract all time-items you need from `new Date()`, please follow the link provided in my answer. Just remember, that the time can't contain `:`. If you need help when formatting a timestamp, maybe you should ask a new question about it, formatting dates is totally different issue from saving an Excel file.